# Are variables primitives and objects themselves in Java (Term related question)?

Tags: java

I have read the Java specs, which say a variable is "a storage location and has an associated type, sometimes called its compile-time type, that is either a primitive type (§4.2) or a reference type (§4.3)." Now I understand that a variable will either contain a primitive value or an object reference. I understand technically a variable is not an object, it is a reference to an object, but we loosely call it an object. Would the same be applied to a variable holding a primitive value? The actual primitive is the value inside the variable, but can we call the variable a primitive as well? I understand that the variable is a primitive data type. This is more of a technical term question.

Comment: There are two types of variables primitive like int,char,float and there are non-primitive aswell as for definition Non-primitive data types are called reference types because they refer to objects. So variables which refer to other objects are non-primitive they does not contain the data but rather reference. So technically variable can be primitive and objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand technically a variable is not an object, it is a reference to an object, but we loosely call it an object.

We don't 'loosely call it an object'. 
**A variable is not an object.**

> Would the same be applied to a variable holding a primitive value? .. but can we call the variable a primitive as well?

**A variable is not a primitive either.**

What then is a variable?

It is as you mentioned,

> a storage location

So a variable is merely a **named storage area** in the memory, whether the area contains a primitive or an object reference has nothing to do with anything except determining the type of the variable.